# ExitFullScreen button causes problems with MPMoviePlayerViewController and presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated

Tags: iphone, url, uiviewcontroller, mpmovieplayercontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

here is my situation :

I call a local movie with an URL. the function is in a custom viewController

in .h :

```
MPMoviePlayerViewController* modalVideoController
```

in .m

```
-(void)startVideoAd:(NSNotification*)notification
{
  NSURL* url = (NSURL*)[notification object];
```

// no problem with url ... already check :)

```
  modalVideoController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
  [modalVideoController shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:YES];
  [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:modalVideoController];

  [modalVideoController release];
}
```

Problem : if the user hit the enter/exit fullscreen button (the double arrow button at right of the fastfoward button in the video button panel), the modalviewController normaly disappear but the video still playing , no images just sounds.

is there a way to kill the video after the button is pressed ?

Comment: This probably doesn't help with your issue, but `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` is not meant to be called by you.  It's an override of `UIViewController`'s implementation so that the movie can be rotated to landscape.

Comment: I find the answer. the idea was to put modalVideoController variable to global and then in viewDidAppear of the mainviewController, test if the modalvideocontroller != nil and then called [modalVideoController.moviePlayer stop].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    // avoid exitFullscreen button problem on FullScreen mode
    if(modalVideoController != nil)
    {
        [modalVideoController.moviePlayer stop];
    }   
}
```

this way stop correctly the movie. Last details: modalVideoController became global.